# Deploying symfony to Heroku, get swiftmailer parameters via configvars

Tags: symfony, variables, heroku, config, swiftmailer

I have deployed my symfony app to Heroku, but I want to configure the swiftmailer component with config_vars provided by Heroku. I already have two of them:

1. SYMFONY_ENV: prod
2. CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL: my-connection-string

Now what I would like to do is to decribe swiftmailer credentials in the config_prod.yml:

```
#config_prod.yml

swiftmailer:
    transport: "%env(mail_transport)%"
    host:      "%env(mail_host)%"
    username:  "%env(mail_user)%"
    password:  "%env(mail_password)%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

I, then, set up the config_vars on Heroku, however when trying to deploy the app I got the following exception.

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvParameterException]
Incompatible use of dynamic environment variables "mail_transport" found in parameters.

[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]
Unable to replace alias "swiftmailer.mailer.default.transport.real" with actual definition "%env(mail_transport)%".

[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
You have requested a non-existent service "%env(mail_transport)%".

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception
```

If I hardcode the parameters in the config.yml then deploying to Heroku succeeds.

What am I messing up? Thx in advance.

Comment: how did you get the email to work on heroku?

Comment: @Baig
in config_prod.yml I used the following configuration  

swiftmailer: 
 transport: smtp  
    host:      smtp.sendgrid.net  
    username:  "%env(SENDGRID_USERNAME)%"  
    password:  "%env(SENDGRID_PASSWORD)%"  
    port: 587

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about heroku but i know how to get ENV_VAR inside symfony config ;)

inside `app/config` where your other configs files reside create a new file called `parameters.php`

```php
<?php
if(isset($_SERVER['AWS_MAILER_HOST']) ){
    $container->setParameter('mailer_transport', @$_SERVER['AWS_MAILER_TRANSPORT']);
    $container->setParameter('mailer_host', @$_SERVER['AWS_MAILER_HOST']);
    $container->setParameter('mailer_username', @$_SERVER['AWS_MAILER_USERNAME']);
    $container->setParameter('mailer_password', @$_SERVER['AWS_MAILER_PASSWORD']);
    $container->setParameter('mailer_port', @$_SERVER['AWS_MAILER_PORT']);
    $container->setParameter('mailer_encryption', @$_SERVER['AWS_MAILER_ENCRYPTION']);
    $container->setParameter('mailer_auth_mode', @$_SERVER['AWS_MAILER_AUTH_MODE']);
}
```

replace all `'AWS_MAILER_...'` with your `ENVIRONEMENT_VAR`

Inside your `app/config/config.yml` put

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: parameters.php } <------------
```